# avoid automatic linking of debug library for debug lib

Tags: debugging, mfc, linker

I use a third part software library called BCGPro from BCGSoft.  I build the libraries for the Controls.

When I build my main project some how it always links Debug build with debug lib and release build with release version of that lib, even if i provide the release lib in the linker input for debug builds it seems to ignore that.

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

Other alternative is adding _BCGCB_DISABLE_AUTOLINK_ definition before including BCGCBProInc.h:

```
#define _BCGCB_DISABLE_AUTOLINK_
#include "BCGCBProInc.h"
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check BCGCBProInc.h around line 81. The library is added to the linker input libraries list there. You will see that lines 46-50 (I'm looking at version 23, yours might be a bit different) add a D suffix to the library name in debug builds. I only had a quick look, but it seems you will have to edit this file to change this behaviour - I don't see an easy way to override it, apart maybe from defining __BCGCBPROINC_H yourself and linking in the correct .lib either through a pragma or manually in the linker input settings.

That said, I think the real question here is why you'd want to do it, because most likely the answer is simply 'don't do it'.